# Riak returning locked status when storing key

Tags: python, riak

I have a five node riak cluster and am doing some basic application testing with a python RiakClient using pbc.  Code looks something like this:

```
b = riakclient.bucket('test')
item = b.get('key1')
item.data = 'testdata'
item.store()
```

I am getting {error,locked} as a RiakError back.  Once this starts to happen I also get a lot of errors between the cluster nodes that look like this:

```
Handoff receiver for partition 1134123.... exited abnormally ... {error,locked}
```

Any ideas what this might be or how to resolve?  This is riak 2.0.2, thinking about updating but hoping to not have to do that yet.

**update:** this problem manifested itself after the docker (did I mention that?) container I was using was restarted.  After restart the riak process came up but was not in a functioning state despite being marked healthy in the cluster.  A 'sv restart riak' got the cluster back to working.  Still wondering what this means, does not seem to be documented although it does seem to mean the node is in a read-only state.

Comment: searching through the source, I find {error,locked} in [bitcask_lockops:acqure](https://github.com/basho/bitcask/blob/develop/src/bitcask_lockops.erl#L57).  Perhaps Riak didn't shut down cleanly when the container restarted and there were stale lock files?

Answer (score 3):

This was a problem in the shutdown scripts, node was coming up in unclean state.  A restart fixed the issue.